# Is it quite bad practice to access DbContext in application?

Tags: .net, design-patterns, repository, ef-code-first

I ussualy see repository pattern samples which encapsulate CRUD methods and even simples extension methods. I found it really annoying to create repository methods which i can already easily use by DbContext. If reason is to creating loose coupling between DbContext and whole application so we can already do this by extract DbContext to interface and use it in whole application.

So it looks better to access DbContext as member of repository for such as simple methods instead of wrapping them by repository. What do you think ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using the DbContext directly inside business logic or (heaven forbid!) display logic code is a serious violation of the "separation of concern" principle, and tends to make your code:

- Harder to maintain: If you decided to refactor how your DbContext is created, you now have to look through your entire code base to change every `new DbContext`.
- Harder to unit test: Entity Framework contexts are notoriously difficult to "mock," whereas a simple repository method on an interface can easily be mocked to return some sample data.

Comment: I haven't talked about instantiate objects. We can easily achieve that problem by DI containers.

Comment: @Freshblood: Good point. I guess all the code I've seen where people access their contexts directly has been hacky/hastily-thrown-together code which doesn't use DI properly. As a rule, separating your business layer from your data layer does help to promote more modular code, but Diego is right in pointing out that smaller, simpler projects can probably get by all right without separating their layers.

Answer (score 4):

While in principle I agree with StriplingWarrior ideas, if you are building a simpler architecture where your business layer uses DbContext properties/methods, there's nothing wrong with it, particularly if you are using an interface for the DbContext and injecting it.

Remember to also use IDbSet instead of DbSet to make it easily mockable.